# What is the best option designing a third-order filter

Tags: active-filter

I have a quick design question. I am designing a third-order low-pass filter that I factorized in a first-order section and then a second-order section, with quality factor 1. Now I am thinking about a circuit to do this and I have the following questions:

- the gain of my circuit is 10 (20 dB). What is the best way to split the gain in a design point of view? Equal gain in both sections? Everything in one? What is the best criterium?
- Does the order of the sections matter?

Thank you!

Comment: I dont have a perfect answer, but I believe it will depend a lot on your requirements regarding noise, input and output levels and how your filter stages are powered.  Can you provide more information about your specific case?

Comment: I'm just doing it by simulation, having no constraints in terms of that! It is just the gain split and sections order that is bothering me!

Comment: yes, but for what purpose are you designing this? "best option" only makes sense if you have anything by which we can measure "bestness".

Comment: Active filters are generally noisy, so put your simple RC filter with gain (assuming RC filter followed by a simple opamp gain stage) ahead of your active filter. Spice simulation will shed light on noise issues. There are designs for a 3rd order LPF using a single op amp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that would be fun finding out for yourself, so why not try all the combinations and see what comes out of it. First, the transfer functions and the gain are (plots normalized to 1 Hz, not 1 rad):

$$\begin{align}
K&=10 \tag{1} \\
A(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s+1} \tag{2} \\
B(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s^2+s+1} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

1. \$H(s)=B(s)\cdot[K\cdot A(s)]\$ (black traces)
2. \$H(s)=[K\cdot B(s)]\cdot A(s)\$ (blue)
3. \$H(s)=A(s)\cdot [K\cdot B(s)]\$ (red)
4. \$H(s)=[K\cdot A(s)]\cdot B(s)\$ (green)

[image: test]

The overall outputs (upper plots) are all overlapping, which is to be expected due to commutativity. The bottom plots show the intermediary responses, and you can see that wherever the gain was used in the first stage (2nd case, blue, and 4th case, green), the intermediary responses are \$20\;\mathrm{dB}\$ higheer than the other two. And between these other two, if the 2nd order stage was used first there is a peaking (1st case, black), whereas if the 1st order is the forst stage (3rd case, red).

The conclusion for these cases is that the best way would be to have the 1st order as the first stage and the 2nd order with the gain as the second stage. But this *best* refers here to the signal magnitude, since this is the the best that an `.AC` analysis can give. You could also infer that the peaking will avoid longer and wilder transients and, thus, the signal integrity (e.g. non-saturated) will not suffer, but other details may need different considerations, as hinted by [Jakob Halskov](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574805/what-is-the-best-option-designing-a-third-order-filter#comment1505933_574805). Still, the above arrangement of stages will be a better choice, in general.

Comment: Just a comment that crossed my mind for odd-order, where there is a 1st order active stage. In general, I think you want to arrange the stages so that those with higher damping are found earlier. And since your analytic 2nd order stage doesn't include damping, explicitly, it's damping is 0.5, which is under-damped. So it's damping is less than a 1st order and it is logical to make it follow. But if you did a general analysis and tried all this with an over-damped 2nd order, as well, you might find the reverse suggestion, placing the 1st order in last position.

Comment: @jonk You're right, that is true and the convergence point for the conclusion (maybe it needs to be added in clear?). But if it's anything below critically damped then there won't ever be any peaking. The signal will not risk any saturation or distortion, so the order will not matter as much. In fact, those cases could as well be considered through an analogy with the passive filters. Still, Jakob's hints apply here, too.